# Запуск макроса Excel из c#

Tags: c#, excel

Добрый день. Есть файл excel,  в котором прикручена кнопка. Необходимо из кода C# запустить этот файл (тут не проблема) и нажать эту кнопку (вот тут не знаю как).

Comment: Кнопка VB макрос запускает, значит этот макрос можно запустить из кода на C#, не?

Comment: а документ можно как то просканить на VB макросы и запустить?

Comment: может можно на контролы проверить и запустить ?

Comment: Извините, я сам офисные приложения не писал, я лишь вам идею подкинул :)

Comment: ну я в этом ключе сейчас и попробую сделать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

оказывается есть такая функция `app.Run("macrosname");`

Comment: Вот и молодец :)